# What is the Value of x

Tags: probability

A bag contains only red, blue and white counters. 
A counter is chosen at random.
The probability it is a blue counter is 4/x
The probability it is a white counter is 7/x-3
The probability it is a red counter is 1/2

Work out the value of x

Is the answer x = 10?

Comment: Hint: You know that the sum of the probabilities must equal a specific amount. Use this equation to solve for $x$

Comment: I, like you, am relatively new to stack-exhange too, but I will nevertheless tell you, please describe what you have already tried yourself. It is a bit disrespectful to simply post a raw question as if this website were a homework help forum. By personally engaging in your questions, you will also deepen your own understanding :)!

Comment: I can put the equation together and say it equals 1 but everything I try afterwords seems to get me no where? Do I move the 1 across and try make x-3 the subject for a start or am I going wrong?

Comment: Parentheses, please.  By 7/x-3 do you mean $7/(x-3)$ or $(7/x)-3?$  Nominally, it should be the latter because division has higher priority than subtraction.  I suspect you mean the former.  The latter is easier to answer.

Comment: It's the first one.

Comment: It must be more than $x=10$ because the probability of a white one would be $1$.

Comment: Since OP got $x = 10$, I'll say a word about solving @Alijah's equation. Suggest begin by multiplying both sides of the equation by $2x(x-3)$ to clear the denominators. Then simplify. You should get $x^2-25x+24=0$. Solve by factoring. Only one of the roots is a viable solution to the problem.

Comment: Do you times the 2x(x-3) by the top numbers of the fraction? I have no idea tbh.

Answer (score 2):

As the probabilities have to sum to $1$, you have

$$\frac{4}{x}+\frac{7}{x-3}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$

Now you can solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Require the probabilities to sum to 1. The result is an equation you can solve for $x$.

Originally I wasn't going to elaborate this answer, but in response to OP's question in the comments I'll spell out the steps.

$${4\over x} + {7\over x-3} + {1\over 2} = 1\,.$$

Multiply both sides of the equation by $2x(x-3)$:

$$2x(x-3)\cdot {4\over x} + 2x(x-3)\cdot {7\over x-3} + 2x(x-3)\cdot {1\over 2} = 2x(x-3) \\ \hbox{$\ $} \\ \hbox{$\ $} \\ {2x(x-3)\over 1}\cdot {4\over x} + {2x(x-3)\over 1}\cdot {7\over x-3} + {2x(x-3)\over 1}\cdot {1\over 2} = 2x(x-3) \\ \hbox{$\ $} \\ \hbox{$\ $} \\ 
{2x(x-3)\cdot 4\over x} + {2x(x-3)\cdot 7\over x-3} + {2x(x-3)\cdot 1\over 2} = 2x(x-3)\,.$$

In each fraction, something will cancel between the numerator and denominator. This gets rid of the fractions in the problem altogether, leading to
$$8(x-3) + 14x + x(x-3)=2x(x-3)\,.$$
This simplifies as
$$x^2-25x+24 = 0\,.$$
This factors as $(x-1)(x-24) = 0$, so either $x=1$ or $x=24$. The solution $x=1$ is not viable in our problem, because it would lead to a probability for red of $-{7\over 2}$, and probaabilities can't be negative. The solution $x=24$ however is viable and leads to probabilities ${1\over 6}$, ${1\over 3}$, ${1\over 2}$. (Actually, one might have guessed this up front.)

Instead of multiplying through by $2x(x-3)$, one might have approached the problem instead by putting all the fractions over a common denominator:

$${4[2(x-3)] + 7[(x)(2)] + 1[(x)(x-3)]\over 2x(x-3)} = 1\,.$$

Now cross-multiply to obtain

$$4[2(x-3)] + 7[(x)(2)] + 1[(x)(x-3)] = 2x(x-3)\,.$$
Expand everything out, simplify, and there results $x^2-25x+24 = 0$ as above.

Now if algebra at this level is daunting, and all you needed to do was to produce a final answer, then I'd point out that you could also consult a graphing calculator or computer program to find the solutions of the original equation numerically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My teacher showed me how to do it by taking 1/2 from both sides then cross multiplying the other fractions and going on to get the same answer.

Comment: @H.cowper Oh that was smart! Thanks for the update. :-)

Comment: No problem. I seem to get through the whole paper resonanbly well but the last question is always a killer so thanks for the help.